# Compile two targets with one Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

---Full Makefile at the bottom ---

I'm currently finishing a project, so I'm coming to the packaging/compiling part.
I'm working with Make, and the specificity of my project is that it contains two projects with a main() in each of them.

I want a binary of the first project (named 'shell') and a binary of the second one (named 'ls'). I've edited the Makefile to separate targets, sources files, etc. Here are the important lines:

```
-- Projects --
TARGET_SHELL = shell
TARGET_LS = ls

-- Directories --
SOURCE = ./src
BIN = ./bin
DIRLIST = ${SOURCE} ${BIN}

-- Targets --
BINSHELL = ${TARGET_SHELL:%=${BIN}/%}
BINLS = ${TARGET_LS:%=${BIN}/%}

-- Files --
SRC_SHELL = ${wildcard ${SOURCE}/execution.c ${SOURCE}/shell.c}
SRC_LS = ${wildcard ${SOURCE}/commande_ls.c}
INT_SHELL = ${wildcard ${SOURCE}/execution.h}
INT_LS = ${wildcard ${SOURCE}/commande_ls.h}
OBJ_SHELL = ${SRC_SHELL:%.c=%.o}
OBJ_LS = ${SRC_LS:%.c=%.o}

-- Rules --
all : ${BINSHELL} ${BINLS}

-- Binaries --
${BIN}/${TARGET_SHELL} : ${${TARGET_SHELL}:%=${SOURCE}/%}
${BIN}/${TARGET_LS} : ${${TARGET_LS}:%=${SOURCE}/%}

${BIN}/% : $(OBJ_SHELL)
    @echo
    @echo Linking bytecode : $@
    @echo ----------------
    @echo
    ${CC} -o $@ $^ ${LDFLAGS}
    @echo
    @echo Done
    @echo
```

The 'make' command works perfectly. At the end, I have two binaries, one named 'shell' and the other one named 'ls'. Nice!

But in fact, the two binaries are exactly the same, they both execute the 'shell' project. I wanted the binary 'shell' to execute the 'shell' project, and the binary named 'ls' to execute the 'ls' project...

I know that I have to edit the end of the Makefile, but I don't know what :(

Thanks

```
#/// @file 
#/// @brief Generic Makefile for the System 2 project.                                                 
#                                                                                                   
#/// @detail If you just add some library files used by the project.c program, you have nothing to change to compile them if sources are in the ./src directory. To add a new binary, just add the name of the main file in the TARGETS variable.             


#Nom du project
TARGET_SHELL = shell
TARGET_LS = ls

##############
# Constantes #
##############

# Repertoires
SOURCE = ./src
BIN = ./bin
DOCPATH = ${SOURCE}/dox
DOCTARGET = ./doc
DIRLIST = ${SOURCE} ${BIN}
#DEP = ${SOURCE}/depend
#DIRLIST = ${SOURCE} ${BIN} ${OPT} ${DEP}

# Cibles
BINSHELL = ${TARGET_SHELL:%=${BIN}/%}
BINLS = ${TARGET_LS:%=${BIN}/%}

# Commandes
CC = gcc

# Options
CFLAGS = -O0 -g -W -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Werror -mtune=native  -march=native  -std=c99  -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700
LDFLAGS = -lm -W -Wall -pedantic -L. -lm

# Fichiers
DOX = ${wildcard ${DOCPATH}/*.dox} # Sources
SRC_SHELL = ${wildcard ${SOURCE}/divers.c ${SOURCE}/commandes_externes.c ${SOURCE}/commandes_internes.c ${SOURCE}/entities.c ${SOURCE}/execution.c ${SOURCE}/parse.c ${SOURCE}/shell.c} # Sources
SRC_LS = ${wildcard ${SOURCE}/commande_ls.c}
INT_SHELL = ${wildcard ${SOURCE}/divers.h ${SOURCE}/commandes_externes.h ${SOURCE}/commandes_internes.h ${SOURCE}/execution.h ${SOURCE}/parse.h} # Interfaces
INT_LS = ${wildcard ${SOURCE}/commande_ls.h}
OBJ_SHELL = ${SRC_SHELL:%.c=%.o}        # Objets
OBJ_LS = ${SRC_LS:%.c=%.o}

##########
# Regles #
##########

# ALL
all : ${BINSHELL} ${BINLS}

# CLEAN
clean :
    @echo
    @echo Cleaning : object files
    @echo --------
    @echo
    rm -f ${OBJ_SHELL}
    rm -f ${OBJ_LS}

clean-doc :
    @echo
    @echo Cleaning : object files
    @echo --------
    @echo
    rm -fr ${DOCTARGET}

clean-emacs :
    @echo
    @echo Cleaning : emacs back-ups
    @echo --------
    @echo
    rm -f ${SOURCE}/*~
    rm -f ${SOURCE}/\#*\#
    rm -f *~
    rm -f \#*\#

clean-bin :
    @echo
    @echo Cleaning : binaries
    @echo --------
    @echo
    rm -f ${BINSHELL}
    rm -f ${BINLS}

distclean : clean clean-emacs clean-bin


dirs : 
    @for dir in ${DIRLIST} ;\
    do \
        echo Creating directory : $${dir} ;\
        echo ------------------ ;\
        if test -d $${dir} ;\
        then \
        echo Directory already exists ;\
        else mkdir -p $${dir} ;\
        fi ;\
        echo Done ;\
        echo ;\
    done

# Binaires
${BIN}/${TARGET_SHELL} : ${${TARGET_SHELL}:%=${SOURCE}/%}
${BIN}/${TARGET_LS} : ${${TARGET_LS}:%=${SOURCE}/%}

${BIN}/% : $(OBJ_SHELL)
    @echo
    @echo Linking bytecode : $@
    @echo ----------------
    @echo
    ${CC} -o $@ $^ ${LDFLAGS}
    @echo
    @echo Done
    @echo

# Regles generiques
%.o : %.c %.h 
    @echo
    @echo Compiling $@
    @echo --------
    @echo
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Documentation 
doc : ${SRC} ${INT} ${DOX}
    doxygen; doxygen

#############################
# Inclusion et spécificités #
#############################

.PHONY : all clean clean-doc clean-emacs clean-bin distclean doc
```

Comment: What you don't don't make sense, why do you use wildcard if you precise a file?  and this is not a valid makefile.

Comment: Yes I forgot to remove the wildcards, thanks. And my file is valid, I just didn't put its whole content here on my post.

Comment: `-- Projects --` is not a valid comment

Comment: I know it's only for this post, to make my Makefile more readable :)

Comment: Use proper way to comment a makefile `# -- Projects --` if you want but don't make your makefile invalid.

Comment: @John Kerman, use copy&paste to post your makefile for best results. Some vital bits can be easily lost with manual editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some fun with very dynamic makefile:

```
#
# Boilerplate.
#
define add_target
    $(info add_target($1))
    $(eval $(eval_args))
    $(eval $(call eval_args,$1,\
        OBJDIR := $(firstword $($1.OBJDIR) ./objs/$1),\
    ))
    $(eval $(call eval_args,$1,\
        objs := $(obj_from_source),
    ))
    $(eval $1 := $($1.TARGET))

    TARGETS += $($1)
    PHONY_TARGETS += $1
    CLEAN_TARGETS += clean_$1

    .PHONY: clean_$1
    clean_$1:; rm -rf $($1.OBJDIR) $($1)

    .PHONY: $1
    $1: $($1)

    $($1): target:=$1
    $($1): $($1.objs); $$(if $$(wildcard $$(@D)),,mkdir -p $$(@D) && )$$(add_target.link)
    $($1.objs):; $$(if $$(wildcard $$(@D)),,mkdir -p $$(@D) && )$$(add_target.compile)
    $(foreach $1.SOURCES,$($1.SOURCES),$(eval $(obj_from_source): $($1.SOURCES)))

    $(info end)
endef

void :=
space := $(void) $(void)
obj_from_source = $(addprefix $($1.OBJDIR)/,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(notdir $($1.SOURCES)))))
eval_args = $(foreach i,2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9,$(call eval_arg,$1,$(strip $($i))))
eval_arg = $(if $2,$(info $(space)$(space)$1.$2)$(eval $1.$2))

# Link command line
add_target.link = $(CC) $($(target).LDLAGS) -o $@ $^

# Compile command line
add_target.compile = $(CC) -c -o $@ $($(target).CFLAGS) $<


# -- Directories --
SOURCE := ./src
BIN := ./bin


# Add 'shell' target to the project
$(eval $(call add_target,shell,\
    TARGET := $(BIN)/shell,\
    SOURCES += ${SOURCE}/execution.c,\
    SOURCES += ${SOURCE}/shell.c,\
    CFLAGS := -Wall -I./include,\
))

# Add 'ls' target to the project
$(eval $(call add_target,ls,\
    TARGET := $(BIN)/ls,\
    SOURCES := $(addprefix ${SOURCE}/,execution.c commande_ls.c),\
    CFLAGS := -I./include,\
))


all: ${PHONY_TARGETS}
.PHONY: all

clean: | $(CLEAN_TARGETS)
.PHONY: clean
```

Environment:

```
$ find
.
./include
./include/execution.h
./src
./src/commande_ls.c
./src/execution.c
./src/shell.c
```

Source files:

```
$ for f in `find -type f`; do echo $f; cat $f; echo; done
./include/execution.h
void workload();

./src/commande_ls.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "execution.h"
int main() {
    printf("Welcome to ls\n");
    workload();
}
./src/execution.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "execution.h"
void workload() {
    printf("Hello from %s\n", __FILE__);
}

./src/shell.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "execution.h"
int main() {
    printf("Welcome to shell\n");
    workload();
}
```

Build all targets:

```
$ make -f ../Makefile.sample
add_target(shell)
  shell.TARGET := ./bin/shell
  shell.SOURCES += ./src/execution.c
  shell.SOURCES += ./src/shell.c
  shell.CFLAGS := -Wall -I./include
  shell.OBJDIR := ./objs/shell
  shell.objs := $(obj_from_source)
end
add_target(ls)
  ls.TARGET := ./bin/ls
  ls.SOURCES := ./src/execution.c ./src/commande_ls.c
  ls.CFLAGS := -I./include
  ls.OBJDIR := ./objs/ls
  ls.objs := $(obj_from_source)
end
mkdir -p objs/shell && cc -c -o objs/shell/execution.o -Wall -I./include src/execution.c
cc -c -o objs/shell/shell.o -Wall -I./include src/shell.c
mkdir -p bin && cc  -o bin/shell objs/shell/execution.o objs/shell/shell.o
mkdir -p objs/ls && cc -c -o objs/ls/execution.o -I./include src/execution.c
cc -c -o objs/ls/commande_ls.o -I./include src/commande_ls.c
cc  -o bin/ls objs/ls/execution.o objs/ls/commande_ls.o
```

Run targets:

```
$ ./bin/ls.exe; ./bin/shell.exe
Welcome to ls
Hello from src/execution.c
Welcome to shell
Hello from src/execution.c
```

Clean `ls` and build all targets again (just for fun):

```
$ make -f ../Makefile.sample clean_ls
add_target(shell)
  shell.TARGET := ./bin/shell
  shell.SOURCES += ./src/execution.c
  shell.SOURCES += ./src/shell.c
  shell.CFLAGS := -Wall -I./include
  shell.OBJDIR := ./objs/shell
  shell.objs := $(obj_from_source)
end
add_target(ls)
  ls.TARGET := ./bin/ls
  ls.SOURCES := ./src/execution.c ./src/commande_ls.c
  ls.CFLAGS := -I./include
  ls.OBJDIR := ./objs/ls
  ls.objs := $(obj_from_source)
end
rm -rf ./objs/ls ./bin/ls

$ make -f ../Makefile.sample
add_target(shell)
  shell.TARGET := ./bin/shell
  shell.SOURCES += ./src/execution.c
  shell.SOURCES += ./src/shell.c
  shell.CFLAGS := -Wall -I./include
  shell.OBJDIR := ./objs/shell
  shell.objs := $(obj_from_source)
end
add_target(ls)
  ls.TARGET := ./bin/ls
  ls.SOURCES := ./src/execution.c ./src/commande_ls.c
  ls.CFLAGS := -I./include
  ls.OBJDIR := ./objs/ls
  ls.objs := $(obj_from_source)
end
mkdir -p objs/ls && cc -c -o objs/ls/execution.o -I./include src/execution.c
cc -c -o objs/ls/commande_ls.o -I./include src/commande_ls.c
cc  -o bin/ls objs/ls/execution.o objs/ls/commande_ls.o
```

Note how handy `$(add_target)` function is. It provides way add as many targets to your project as you need without stupid code duplication. Still configuring of target build options is extremely flexible.

Should work with GNU Make 3.81 and up. Enjoy!

Comment: looks great! I'm trying it in a few minutes, will let you know if it worked

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working because I also have to include .h files that are required in my .c files. In your Makefile, where do I have to include .h files to both targets? Thanks a lot

Comment: @John Kerman, updated my answer with handling `#includes`-s. Note, that I just have adjusted value of `CFLAGS` property passed into `$(add_target)` function to instruct compiler where to look for headers. No changes to boilermake.

Comment: it works, at least for the 'ls' one ;) I'm trying for the 'shell'. By the way, why do you use `addprefix` in the ls target but not in the shell one?

Comment: @John Kerman, `addprefix` in one case and `SOURCES +=` in another just to demonstrate flexibility of the solution. Please keep in mind `add_target` is just a starting point. Very good starting point compared to common solutions with implicit rules :), but still. You will probably would like to extend it with ability to track changes in .h files referenced from `#include` directives of your sources and rebuild .o files. Once you understand how `add_target` works you can extend it to better fit in you needs.

Comment: All right! Looks very powerful compared to what I already saw

Comment: Right. Similar approach is used in Open JDK build system starting from JDK8. This is quite a large project. Its previous build system was based on recursive make invocations. Something suggested by @Vetinari . It was never ending pain. Dynamic makefiles look odd and unusual at first glance, but they work really well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this:

```
SUBDIRS := common programs

all: subdir

ifdef SUBDIRS
.PHONY: subdir $(SUBDIRS)
subdir: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -s -C $@ <--  ${BIN...
endif
```

SUBDIRS --> TARGET...

Comment: I don't get it? What SUBDIRS does represent in my case? I only have one folder with all my source files

Comment: Recursive makefiles are absolute evil.

Comment: Substitute  SUBDIRS with or TARGET, it is just an example for using

Comment: substitute SUBDIRS with TARGET, it is just an example for using a list